# How to iterate JSON object in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

I create json object like this

`id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                              options:kNilOptions
                                                error:&error];`

But the document does not tell me how to loop the `json` object by keys and values.

Comment: Depending on the string you will either get back `NSDictionary` or `NSArray`.  After that you can iterate over them as your normally would.

Answer (score 6):

Here is one way to do it. I'll be happy to get into more details if you make your question more specific.

```
    NSString *jsonString = @"[{\"id\": \"1\", \"name\":\"Aaa\"}, {\"id\": \"2\", \"name\":\"Bbb\"}]";
    NSData *data = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSError *e = nil;
    NSArray *jsArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&e];

if (!jsArray) {
  NSLog(@"Error parsing JSON: %@", e);
} else {
   for(NSDictionary *item in jsArray) {
      NSLog(@"Item: %@", item);
      NSLog(@"%@",[item objectForKey:@"id"]);
      NSLog(@"%@",[item objectForKey:@"name"]);

   }
}
```

Comment: you mean use `data options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers` this option to return an container object? Returning array or dictionary depends on the json string?

Comment: see my edit above for reading the json string and converting it to NSData. I'm not sure I completely understand your question.

Comment: @guilin桂林 Yes your point is correct. A valid json object will only belong to an array or dictionary. If you want more specific answers, give the structure of your json in the question.