# How to extract particular elements from JSON

Tags: objective-c, arrays, json, ios7

I have a JSON file that looks like this in my project:

```
 {
 "city": [
        {
         "NewYork": [
                          {
                          "url_id": "63",
                          "title": "someTitle"
                          },
                          {
                          "url_id": "62",
                          "title": "someOtherTitle"
                          }
                          ],
         "Boston": [
                          {
                          "url": "68",
                          "title": "someTitle"
                          }
                          ]
   .
   .
   .
```

Then I'm trying to go through it in Objective-C and create an array of only the names of the cities. I'm able to log the whole JSON, or the properties of "New York", but not just the names.

Is my JSON wrong or am I doing something wrong in the code?

**Edit:** I forgot to mention that some cities could have multiple id's and titles so I believe creating dictionaries is out of question? Also I have the data in a file so I'm not creating it in the code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to iterate JSON object in ios](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16996624/how-to-iterate-json-object-in-ios)

Comment: I've looked through this answer and many others. The problem here is that the JSON is made by me so I'm not sure if it's correctly formatted or I'm doing something else wrong.

Comment: *I am a JSON file* either you are a JSON file or your sentence is missing a verb.

Comment: Go to json.org and learn the JSON syntax.  It only takes 5-10 minutes to learn. Then understand that NSJSONSerialization will map JSON "objects" to NSDictionarys and JSON "arrays" to NSArrays.  Refer to the documentation for NSDictionary and NSArray to understand how to operate on those objects.  Everything you need is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This JSON doesn't seem quite right. The `cities` value should just be a dictionary:

```
{
  "cities" : {
    "Boston" : [
      {
        "url_id" : "63",
        "title" : "someTitle"
      },
      {
        "url_id" : "62",
        "title" : "someOtherTitle"
      }
    ],
    "New York" : [
      {
        "url_id" : "63",
        "title" : "someTitle"
      },
      {
        "url_id" : "62",
        "title" : "someOtherTitle"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

If you wanted to get the array of city names from the above JSON, you'd convert this to a dictionary and use `allKeys` of the value returned from the `cities` key:

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:nil];
NSArray *cityNames = [dictionary[@"cities"] allKeys];
```

---

Personally, I think it would be better to make your `cities` value in the JSON an array of dictionaries, where the city name is an attribute of the dictionary:

```
{
  "cities" : [
    {
      "name" : "New York",
      "urls" : [
        {
          "url_id" : "63",
          "title" : "someTitle"
        },
        {
          "url_id" : "62",
          "title" : "someOtherTitle"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name" : "Boston",
      "urls" : [
        {
          "url_id" : "63",
          "title" : "someTitle"
        },
        {
          "url_id" : "62",
          "title" : "someOtherTitle"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

In which case, you'd retrieve the city names like so:

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:nil];
NSArray *cityNames = [dictionary[@"cities"] valueForKey:@"name"];
```

But the JSON proposed in the question seems to have some redundant `[`, IMHO. And I think the key name of `city` is misleading because it contains a number of cities, so I'd instead suggest `cities`.

Comment: Thank you this one worked! Guess I should've checked about JSON syntax a bit more. I just deleted first [] brackets and code started working.

Answer (score 0):

You must create first a dictionary that contains city key and city key must assign to an array.

```
NSDictionary *newYorkDict = {
                              @"url_id":@"63",
                              @"title":@"someTitle"
                              };

  NSDictionary *bostonDict = {@"url_id":@"63",
                                @"title":@"someTitle"
                                };

  NSArray *newYorkArray = [newYorkDict];
  NSArray *bostonArray = [bostonDict];

  NSDictionary *dict = {
                        @"New york":newYorkArray,
                        @"Boston":bostonArray
                        };

  NSArray *cityArray = [dict];

  NSDictionary *mainDict = {@"city":cityArray};
```

Comment: I was thinking to do it straight with dictionaries and arrays, but decided to try with JSON, because some cities would have multiple titles and id's.