# How to get JSON key from a JSON Object with SwiftyJSON?

Tags: json, swift, swifty-json

My JSON object is like this:

```
{
  "Avarage" : "2,5"
}
```

Getting value of the 'Average' is simple. I just do:

`json["Average"].string!`

The question is, how do I actually get the name 'Average'. It is loaded from http request and I must know and use all the names and values from this object.

PS: I'm using SwiftyJSON

Comment: Convert the JSON string into NSDictionary and iterate, See [How to iterate JSON object in ios](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16996624/how-to-iterate-json-object-in-ios)

Comment: Do as suggested in above comment. here is good tutorial https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/libraries/how-to-parse-json-using-swiftyjson

Comment: SwiftyJSON already has parsed and evaluated your JSON. So don't force-unwrap `.string`, use `.stringValue` instead. And for getting the *key* instead of getting the value, look at SwiftyJSON's documentation.

Comment: Thanks, managed to find a solution thanks to you guys.

Answer (score 7):

This one worked for me:

```
for (key, subJson) in json {

}
```

Answer (score -3):

// try like this , it will work for u

```
let jsonData = NSData(string: jsonString)
let dic: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableLeaves) as! NSDictionary
NSLog("key value ===> \(dic.valueForkey("Avarage"))")
```